# How can i use f-string formatting to rewrite a statement:

Tags: python, f-string

I have read and re-read a handful of pages about PEP and literal `string`interpolation.
But still can't figure out through experimentation what exact syntax will work so i can remove the %s from  following statement in my `python` script.

```
cmds.getAttr("%s.fileTextureName" %item, newPath,type="string")
```

Thanks~

Comment: also i can't figure out how to put % or %s as a tag

Comment: `f"{item}.fileTextureName"`? (Assumes `item` isn’t a tuple.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [string.Formatter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

```
cmds.getAttr("{}.fileTextureName".format(item), newPath,type="string")
```

The built-in `str` and `unicode` classes provide the ability to do complex variable substitutions and value formatting via the `str.format()` method described in PEP 3101.
The Formatter class in the string module allows you to create and customize your own string formatting behaviors using the same implementation as the built-in `format()` method.